# Input for LSTM in case of time series data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a (not text) dataset of size (1152,151). I wished to divide this into 8 batches, each containing 144 samples for training a LSTM network with it in Keras. I reshaped the data for sending into a LSTM as (8,144,151). Is this the right input shape? Because when I sent this as input and had return_sequences=False for this layer and the next LSTM layer as well, I got an error:

> expected n_dim=3, got n_dim=2.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((8,144,151))
def deepmodel():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(8,input_shape=(144,151),return_sequences=False))
  model.add(LSTM(8,return_sequences=False))
  model.add(Dense(8))
  model.add(Activation('softmax'))
  adam=Adam()
  model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = adam)
return model
```

Comment: What kind of data is this? If it's a single related sample, it doesn't really makes sense to split in in batches. And from which layer do you get error? Is the first LSTM layer or some other?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will set your batch size in `model.fit(...., batch_size=8)`. Look at the example below, it should clear your error message. If you are looking for multiple time lag, be sure to check out this wonderful [blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-networks-python/).

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
def deepmodel():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(8,input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=False))
  model.add(LSTM(8,return_sequences=False))
  model.add(Dense(8))
  model.add(Activation('softmax'))
  adam=Adam()
  model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = adam)
return model
```